# Good practices for building web application that can later have and mobile(Android/iPhone) version

Tags: iphone, android, architecture

can you advice me a book or something else containing good practices about how to build/structure a web application in a way that will be easy to extend it with an Android/iPhone version later.
I am currently trying to get into Django so it will be nice if the practices are related to it, but every hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just doing Model-View-Controller. If you put all your logic into your controller (which you should), going from a web based application to a mobile one is just writing a new view.